# redirect uri mismatch in google oauth 2

Tags: apex, oauth2, oauth, google

i am trying to implement google oauth2 .i created a web application whem it redirect to OAuth login screen its giving me error : "redirect_uri_mismatch".here is screen shot
[image]

but in google console my app is redirect uri i set is "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/GoogleLogin" and i am using same redirect_uri in my flow.still i am getting this error.can anyone please guideline what is the mistake ??

Comment: suddenly after 15 minutes same everything starts working.

Answer (score 2):

In our internal notes on setting up OATH apps in Facebook and Google we have this:

> Note that it can take a few minutes for these app definitions to
>   propagate across the vendor's infrastructure.

that corresponds to your "after 15 minutes same everything starts working" experience.